# Android: how to ignore rotation around single axis?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm developing application, where activity starts after phone's rotation. When you rotate phone backward that activity have to finish. Is it possible to ignore rotation around other axes?

Answer (score 0):

You can check which way the phone is held with this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

Then you can check the orientation like this:

```
switch (rotation)
{
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        ...
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        ...
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
        break;
}
```

(Note that for pre-API 8 versions you'd need to use `display.getOrientation()` instead of `display.getRotation()`)

Comment: Is it possible to get data about display rotation at the real-time using this code?

Comment: You can use an OrientationEventListener to listen to orientation changes and then test for current orientation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html